# VueJS 3: updated() hook not called eventhough I update data inside mounted() hook

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

So I have been trying to learn Vue, and I have a parent component which has an array thats empty initially, and an isLoading which is false. I use axios to fetch data inside the mounted hook, and update the array with the response data.
To manage loading, I set isLoading to true before the axios call, and set it to false in the resolution of that axios call.

I tried consoling my isLoading data in mounted() and updated() hooks, and updated hook doesnt seem to be called at all.

The actual problem I am trying to solve is, I am passing these two data items inside provide() for another child component to use. The child component correctly shows the data that is fetched using axios in the parent, but isLoading prop is not updated inside the child component when accessed using inject.
I have work arounds like I can check for the length of the array, but I really want to understand what is happening here and why.

Providing the valid code snippets below, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Parent data, provide(), mounted and updated hooks:

```
data() {
    return {
      friends: [],
      isLoading: false,
    };
  },
  provide() {
    return {
      friends: this.friends,
      toggleFavourite: this.toggleFavourite,
      addFriend: this.addFriend,
      isLoading: this.isLoading,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    console.log("mounted -> this.isLoading", this.isLoading);
    axios.get(*url*).then((res) => {
      Object.keys(res.data).forEach((key) => {
        this.friends.push({ ...res.data[key] });
      });
      this.isLoading = false;
      console.log("mounted -> this.isLoading", this.isLoading);
    });
  },
  updated() {
    console.log("updated -> this.isLoading", this.isLoading);
  },
```

Child inject:

```
inject: ["friends", "toggleFavourite", "isLoading"]
```

Child usage of isLoading:

```
<span v-if="isLoading">Loading...</span>
  <div class="friends-container" v-else>
    <friend
      v-for="friend in friends"
      :key="friend.id"
      :name="friend.name"
      :email="friend.email"
      :hobbies="friend.hobbies"
      :age="friend.age"
      :rating="friend.rating"
      :favourite="friend.favourite"
      @toggle-fav="toggleFavourite"
    ></friend>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle-hooks.html#updated) :

> ...in most cases you should avoid changing state inside the hook. To react to state changes, it's usually better to use a computed property or watcher instead.

So you could use a watcher  property like :

```
data() {
    return {
      friends: [],
      isLoading: false,
    };
  },
  provide() {
    return {
      friends: this.friends,
      toggleFavourite: this.toggleFavourite,
      addFriend: this.addFriend,
      isLoading: this.isLoading,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    console.log("mounted -> this.isLoading", this.isLoading);
    axios.get(*url*).then((res) => {
      Object.keys(res.data).forEach((key) => {
        this.friends.push({ ...res.data[key] });
      });
      this.isLoading = false;
      console.log("mounted -> this.isLoading", this.isLoading);
    });
  },
watch:{
  isLoading(newVal,oldVal){
  console.log("watch -> this.isLoading",newVal)
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am not changing the state inside the updated hook. State is changed only inside the mounted hook. However, when state changes inside mounted hook, updated hook should ideally be called right? Why isn't that happening?

Answer (score 0):

The trouble of this is in the `provide` & `inject`. Those are not a reactive data. So when `isLoading` is changed in the ParentComponent it is **not** changed in the ChildComponent. The ChildComponent still has an initial value of `isLoading`.

There are some tricks to solve that, but this is another question.

Hope that helps

Comment: Yeah I found in the docs that they are not reactive, however, updated() hook of parent component should be called when I am changing the isLoading data right? I am trying to understand why even that is not happening.

Comment: Well that depends. The `updated` hook should fire after the Virtual DOM re-render.

Comment: If in your case "re-render does not happened, this is normal behavior that `updated` hook does not fire. Try `beforeUpdate` hook. This one fires after every data changes. 